# HBase Restore Failure on Amazon EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, hbase, apache-zookeeper, emr, amazon-emr

So, I am having a really strange error happening when restoring HBase onto an amazon EMR cluster from an s3 snapshot.

The hbase restore works fine sometimes and other times doesn't -- this is the puzzling part.  It doesn't seem to depend on my instance types or quantity of nodes and it happens so sporadically that I can't pin down what exactly is failing (besides being unable to obtain a master table lock and timing out) and every attempt to google this problem has turned up empty...

My job flow is as follows:

---

Master: 1x  M1.XL

Core: 15x M1.XL  **Spot instances* *

**Bootstrap:**  Setup Hbase (s3://elasticmapreduce/bootstrap-actions/setup-hbase)

**Step1:** Start Hbase (/home/hadoop/lib/hbase.jar emr.hbase.backup.Main --start-master)

**Step2:** Restore Hbase (/home/hadoop/lib/hbase.jar emr.hbase.backup.Main --restore --backup-dir s3://mybackupdir --backup-version mybackupversion)

---

During the restore step, the restore will either fail or succeed (seemingly randomly, but I believe there may be timeout/latency issues here)

It seems that the restore that times out keeps retying to lock the master which after 10 minutes of failing, the step is fails

```
2014-04-02 17:46:57,028 WARN emr.hbase.backup.HBaseConnector (main): Master is not running, proceeding
2014-04-02 17:46:57,029 INFO emr.hbase.backup.Main (main): Attempting to aquire the master lock
2014-04-02 17:47:07,039 INFO emr.hbase.backup.Main (main): Unable to obtain master lock, attempting to shutdown master. java.lang.RuntimeException: Timeout while performing operation, expireTime=1396460818029 msg=obtaining write lock waiting for notification
2014-04-02 17:47:07,039 INFO emr.hbase.backup.HBaseConnector (main): Listing nodes at beginning of shutdown
2014-04-02 17:47:07,039 INFO emr.hbase.backup.HBaseConnector (main): Get master
2014-04-02 17:47:07,043 INFO emr.hbase.backup.ZooKeeperConnection (main-EventThread): Event received WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:None path:null
2014-04-02 17:48:18,370 WARN emr.hbase.backup.HBaseConnector (main): Master is not running, proceeding
2014-04-02 17:48:18,370 INFO emr.hbase.backup.Main (main): Attempting to aquire the master lock
2014-04-02 17:48:18,370 INFO emr.hbase.backup.Main (main): Releasing the lock
2014-04-02 17:48:18,374 FATAL emr.hbase.backup.Main (main): Exception raised in main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Timeout while performing operation, expireTime=1396460846811 msg=Attempting to shutdown master
    at emr.hbase.fs.Utils.throwIfExpired(Utils.java:67)
    at emr.hbase.backup.PerformBackup.restore(PerformBackup.java:201)
```

On the other hand, when it works, despite timing out a couple times on locking the master, it only takes around 3 minutes to start the restore

```
2014-04-01 19:29:43,720 INFO emr.hbase.backup.Main (main): Attempting to aquire the master lock
2014-04-01 19:29:53,730 INFO emr.hbase.backup.Main (main): Unable to obtain master lock, attempting to shutdown master. java.lang.RuntimeException: Timeout while performing operation, expireTime=1396380584720 msg=obtaining write lock waiting for notification
2014-04-01 19:29:53,730 INFO emr.hbase.backup.HBaseConnector (main): Listing nodes at beginning of shutdown
2014-04-01 19:29:53,731 INFO emr.hbase.backup.HBaseConnector (main): Get master
2014-04-01 19:29:53,734 INFO emr.hbase.backup.ZooKeeperConnection (main-EventThread): Event received WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:None path:null
2014-04-01 19:30:32,963 WARN emr.hbase.backup.HBaseConnector (main): Master is not running, proceeding
2014-04-01 19:30:32,963 INFO emr.hbase.backup.Main (main): Attempting to aquire the master lock
2014-04-01 19:30:33,028 INFO emr.hbase.backup.Main (main): Distributed copy from s3://myhbasebackup
2014-03-17 16:30:14,502 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main):  map 0% reduce 0%
2014-03-17 16:30:22,645 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main):  map 100% reduce 0%
2014-03-17 16:30:33,753 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main):  map 100% reduce 1%
2014-03-17 16:30:36,778 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main):  map 100% reduce 2%
2014-03-17 16:30:39,809 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main):  map 100% reduce 5%
2014-03-17 16:30:40,817 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main):  map 100% reduce 8%
                   *...and it works...*
```

I know there are timeout parameters i can change like the zookeeper timeout but Im not sure the timeout limit is actually the problem because ive seen this literally fail once, and work if i retry with exactly the same settings.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: So it seems that anything more than 5 nodes this will almost always happen, and 5 nodes or less It'll **usually * * succeed

Comment: did you find solution to your problem?